# Editable embedded google doc

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, doc

I'm creating a website to tutor people at my school, and I need to embed a google doc so that anyone who visits the page can edit after they log in with their google account ofc. The way I have it now, it is not editable but it does embed. Does anyone know how to do this, can it even be done?
Here is what I have so far.

```html
<iframe src="GOOGLE-DOC-URL" height = "1000" width = "1000"></iframe>
```

I made the page public and published it, I've done quite a lot of looking on this and found that adding "seamless" to the iframe statement used to work but now that is deprecated apparently and I tried that and it does not work. Thank you.

Comment: Hi you need to add the url with param embedded=true

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do add the URL google doc with this params :

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/KEY/pub?embedded=true

Second i do an ajax call to get the information and the response from google doc api :

https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/dVeMmE

To create your own page : the **API doc** will **print** after the **HR** html element

html page :

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>The text below is pulled live from Google Docs</h1>
<h4>If there is an update to the doc and you refresh the page, it should update.</h4>
<hr>
<script>
function get_information(link, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", link, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
};

//Now initilisation and call & working from the anonyme callback function with dom response :

get_information("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yf5plpYBYsBMCaeeDpTkapgR8jZtg4XCfiTvRG5qRWY/pub?embedded=true", function(text) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = text;

    // Remove css that comes with Google Doc embeds
    // If you want the Google Doc styling, comment these out
    div.removeChild(div.childNodes[1]);
    div.removeChild(div.childNodes[0]);

    document.body.appendChild(div);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
  }
 );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had embedded=true. So what this Ajax statement goes in a div element? what am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: First add you url API in the example to load your own google doc and then the doc can be read by the ajax call and the return of this ajax is the ouput of your document google doc. Just try by replacing the URL "red color in the example". Regards. (this isn't a valid url : GOOGLE-DOC-URL)

Comment: This is a example to codepen.io because isn't running as i want. https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/dVeMmE

Comment: A new example here: the URL change the api google doc point to https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZWnn-jtHMU9Qu06_-3p0H2zWgzAjg7wi6r0Z3kv_sAk/edit and the result getting here https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/BwxKOL etc ...

Comment: Okay, how would this look in a single document? The code pen is not really helping me. I'm new with web development. Why is the HTML, CSS, and JS  split into 3 separate fields? How do I make an ajax call? I looked it up and I'm having a hard time understanding how I would put this in my html document.

Comment: yes Javascript try to respect the doc and print all text table ... etc from the doc. the title and all other text adding directly on the document html (go the full example html page in my POST added) you have to to copy/paste. For the ajax call you got the example and is running just try to understand look for tutorial look "at my comment for doc style". now the hard time is the understand from a html with all the script running. i hope that help you. Regards. I have to go bed bye ;).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense to me now. I need to learn xml